# Simple linked list loop detection in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

I tried to implement a simple linked list in Haskell...

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

... and a loop detection algorithm for it:

```
listNext :: List a -> List a
listNext Nil          = Nil
listNext (Cons _ xs) = xs

loopDetecting' :: (Eq a) => List a -> List a -> Bool
loopDetecting' current next
      | current == Nil || next1 == Nil || next2 == Nil  = False
      | current == next1 || current == next2            = True
      | otherwise = loopDetecting' (listNext current) next2
      where
          next1 = listNext next
          next2 | next1 == Nil  = Nil
                | otherwise     = listNext next1

loopDetecting :: (Eq a) =>  List a -> Bool
loopDetecting Nil         = False
loopDetecting (Cons _ xs) = loopDetecting' xs xs
```

However, I got infinite recursion. What is wrong?

Full code here: https://gist.github.com/mrLSD/03381a277c336c1902f9d78b79a131b0

Comment: Detecting loops is impossible.

Comment: `==` tests value equality (by looking at every element of the lists), not pointer equality. Haskell doesn't feature pointers.

Comment: You should state that you are trying to implement the [Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm. This is not possible in pure haskell. With `IO`, it should be possible though.

Comment: There are no looping linked lists in Haskell, as there are no pointers to form a loop. There are infinite lists, but it's not possible to detect one.

Comment: @n.m. Why do you think no looping linked lists here? Looping linked list infinite a-priori.

Comment: @mrLSD Please provide a simple value of type `List a` that contains a loop.

Comment: Of course they are infinite. They also don't exist.

Comment: @chepner Do you not consider values like this to be a linked list with a loop? `let x = Cons 5 x in x`. Of course it's still not a loop you can *detect*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      | current == next1 || current == next2            = True
```

This line uses `==` on two unknown lists. To determine whether two lists are equal, `==` has to walk over their elements. If the lists are infinite, `==` will only return after finding a difference. If they're equal, `==` will never stop.

As for why `==` does this: The compiler-generated `Eq` instance for your type (as provided by `deriving (Eq)`) looks like this:

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (List a) where
    (==) Nil         Nil         = True
    (==) (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = x == y && xs == ys
    (==) _           _           = False
```

The recursion is in the `xs == ys` part.

Comment: Maybe add a note to contrast this to pointer equality, which op is looking for?

Comment: @jpath I don't know what OP is looking for yet. And I don't like the name "pointer equality": You can compare pointers in Haskell (by value), but normal values don't have addresses. So I'd have to contrast this to something that literally doesn't exist in Haskell (with an additional note that it's unrelated to the `Ptr` type).

Comment: They don't have to exist in Haskell, to compare them to value equality. I just thought it would be helpful, as OP probably comes from a procedural background and it would help him understand why he can do this in which ever language he is coming from but not so easily in Haskell. But maybe he can figure it out and it's fine.

Comment: @melpomene I made conclusion, that with pure Haskell, it is impossible detect infinite loop for subject? IO my way?

Comment: @mrLSD Given your data type, you can't detect cycles in it. It may be possible for a different data structure (e.g. one with explicit pointers).

Comment: This answer as stands is perfectly correct, but [the claim that you cannot detect cycles in pure data types is entirely false.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify)

Comment: @user2407038 That 1) looks like black magic and 2) seems to be undocumented. (I see it uses `unsafeCoerce`, and according to the description it "*can be used safely even with unsafePerformIO if some simple conditions are met*" but those conditions are never explained.) But even so I'm pretty sure it only detects "physical" cycles (where the underlying implementation points back to existing nodes), not "logical" cycles where values just happen to repeat (I think `iterate (\n -> succ n \`div\` 2) 0` is an example of the latter.)

Comment: @melpomene There is a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4838/bd0a91b3058b467fa31ad9e0810121b46388.pdf), but we are on stackoverflow and not math.stackexchange.  And indeed, the concepts of definitional cycles and semantic cycles are entirely orthogonal, in Haskell. The question seems to be about the latter and the answer addresses that exactly. The former is invariably brought up whenever 'detecting cycles' is mentioned.